# Build a module from another kernel

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules

Is it possible to use a module (wacom) from a more recent kernel ? My current kernel is 3.1.2 and the module is from kernel 3.4rc4.

Answer (score 4):

It varies, sometimes the dependencies of a kernel module has changed too much but for the wacom module it does not matter.

By the way, you can get the wacom kernel module source from http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/. I recommend you to use DKMS for building custom kernel modules. I've packaged a package for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~lekensteyn/+archive/wacom-tablet/+sourcepub/2381407/+listing-archive-extra If you're not familiar with Ubuntu or Debian packaging, the .debian.tar.gz file contains packaging scripts.

Comment: So, if I compile only the wacom module it may work ? by the way i am using opensuse and i am trying to make Intuos5 tablet work.

Comment: It should work, the kernel requirements are still like 2.6.37